# Foreign Class not populating after save in mvc 4

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am saving data using Ajax and at the same time I want it to display in list. below is Class of City

```
       public class City
       {
           [Key]
           public int Id { get; set; }
           [Required]
           public string Name { get; set; }
           [Required]
           public int StateId { get; set; }
           [ForeignKey("StateId")]
           public virtual State state { get; set; }
      }
```

my Post method is

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EditCity(City obj)
        {
            try
            {
                aRepository.Save(obj);
                var db = aRepository.Citys.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == obj.Id);
                return PartialView("_iCity", db);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

        }
```

Here `db.state = null`, it's not populating.

Comment: use `.include` in the code

Comment: please explain how??

Comment: If I'll write var db = aRepository.Citys.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == obj.Id); it gets data. when i'm not saving

Comment: check the ans that i've given

Answer (score 0):

Should get you the state detail by :

or

```
var db = aRepository.Citys.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == obj.Id).Include(x=>x.StateId);
```

Comment: what about .Include(x=>x.StateId); ?

Comment: nop! there isn't any method like Include(x=>x.StateId);

Answer (score 0):

When you post the data for your server, your ViewModel should has `StateId`, if you are passing the Object state into it, by default Etity Framework will not persist.

I suppose you are using [Lazy Loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd456846(v=vs.100).aspx) , so you dont need to user `Include` to get the `State` entity

Comment: how to get that state ? If I write the same code for getting the city it populate, but in this case when i am updating or saving, it's not get populated